# How to make conversation window with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problems building a conversation window between 2 ppl, it is Always broken :(

My idea to have at the top located div with some info about one user and then on the bottom fixed tekst area with send button.

And in the middle place where the messages would be shown ...

here is what i've got, but it is totally broken :(

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R4ybW/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-height" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Favorite</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ignore</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Report</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Location</p>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p><b>Seller 1</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hello, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1</p>
    <p><b>Buyer 2</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hi, hi, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1</p>
    <p><b>Seller 1</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hello, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1, message 1</p>
    <p><b>Buyer 2</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hi, hi, i'm glad you wrote me, lets talk first</p>
    <p><b>Seller 1</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hello, how are you? I just saw you and would like to meet!</p>
    <p><b>Buyer 2</b> 
    </p>
    <p>Hi, hi, i'm glad you wrote me, lets talk first</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it with bootstrap.

here is how I would like to have it look like:

[image]

Anyone can eleborate .... please???

Comment: You had a minor HTML issue, but it's still not bad. Here's a fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R4ybW/2 What's the question, exactly?

Comment: oh nice, thanks, but yeah the footer is not fixed :( it is not on the bottom :/ of the screen, and the orange drop down list, i can't place on the left as well as the name and location next to the pic :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding mostly to your comment above, here are some starter solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R4ybW/4

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

<img ... class="pull-left" />
<button type="button" class="... pull-right"> ...
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"> ...
```